# issue adding images to buttons using visual studios 2022 C# for revit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, revit-api

I'm running into an issue where everything works fine until I try to throw in the images. I'm trying to pull them in as resources from inside vs. Not sure what to do here being new to C#. Below is the code that's throwing me the errors. as well as the error message.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO8UG.png)

```
#region Namespaces
using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Media;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Drawing; 
#endregion

namespace TpMechanical
{
    internal class App : IExternalApplication
    {
        public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication a)
        {
            String tabname = "TpMechanical";
            String panelname = "Tools";
          
            Bitmap button1Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)TpMechanical.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Untitled design.png");
            Bitmap button2Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)TpMechanical.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Untitled design2.png");
            Bitmap button3Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)TpMechanical.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Untitled design3.png");


            a.CreateRibbonTab(tabname);
            var Tools = a.CreateRibbonPanel(tabname, panelname);
            var button1 = new PushButtonData("TpButton1", "Button1", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "TpMechanical.command");
            button1.ToolTip = " This is a short description";
            button1.LongDescription = "This is a long description \n " +
                "this is the second line";
            var btn1 = Tools.AddItem(button1);

            var button2 = new PushButtonData("TpButton2", "Button2", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "TpMechanical.command2");
            button2.ToolTip = " This is a short description";
            button2.LongDescription = "This is a long description \n " +
                "this is the second line";
   
            var button3 = new PushButtonData("TpButton3", "Button3", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "TpMechanical.command3");
            button3.ToolTip = " This is a short description";
            button3.LongDescription = "This is a long description \n " +
                "this is the second line";
            
            Tools.AddStackedItems(button2, button3);
            

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication a)
        {
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the error message as plain text as it helps to find similar questions.

Comment: Wont let me because it contains code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing an image from Resources using the standard bitmap library in c#

`Bitmap b1Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)(WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Name of the image"));`

You will need to replace "WindowsFormsApp1" with the correct namespace.

As you are using System.Windows.Media.Imaging you will need:

```
BitmapImage b1Image = (System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage)(WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Name of the image"));
```

Comment: I may be missing a reference. It gives me an error saying "the type namespace name "Properties" doesn't exist in the namespace "TpMechanical".

Comment: Right click on the Project inside VS, then click on Properties.

Find Resources in the Menu on the left, then click on "Create or open assembly resources" or similar message.  This should create the default Resources.resx under a new Properties Folder/Namespace.

Then the code should work

You will need to add the images that you want to load into the Resources.resx via VS before you try and compile the code.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm headed in the right direction now. now I'm having this pop up but I'm guessing it's because I'm using pngs instead of jpegs. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' TpMechanical C:\My Revit- Custom Files\01-Revit 2021\Revit 2021 Repos\TpMechanical\App.cs 27 Active

Comment: No that is an error because the types mismatch.

Is there a reason you are using the 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' namespace instead of the standard System.Drawing.Bitmap?

The 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging' namespace is a special namespace for loading XAML Bitmaps?

Comment: No that was just recommended from the blogs I had came across. I changed it to the standard and no errors but the images wont show on the buttons. I just edited the post to show my script.

Comment: Try the extra code I have just added above, there might be a reason you are using that library, and or the rest of your code is expecting that format now.

Comment: Never mind user error. It works!! Thanks a ton. Idk how to accept solutions on here, used to autodesk forums.